# ¿Como hago que mi terminal de visual code y Pitty reconozcan mi teclado ya que no me permite escribir nada?

Tags: terminal

Hola mi terminal de visual code y Pitty no reconoce mi teclado sin embargo el símbolo de sistema de Windows si todo normal pero los demás no saben por qué no funciona ayúdenme xfa

Comment: Te recomendaría que mire https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask para qué tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, haz el recorrido para entender como funciona obtener tu primera medalla http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

Comment: Hola Nicky Ar, SOes es un espacio para dudas de programación. El problema que tu tienes si bien puede que alguien aquí te ayude con el, es preferible que las externes en el lugar adecuado como por ejemplo [superuser](https://superuser.com/)